# tf.keras predictions are bad while evaluation is good

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, tf.keras

I'm programming a model in tf.keras, and running model.evaluate() on the training set usually yields ~96% accuracy. My evaluation on the test set is usually close, about 93%. However, when I predict manually, the model is usually inaccurate. This is my code:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

!git clone https://github.com/DanorRon/data
%cd data
!ls

batch_size = 100
epochs = 15
alpha = 0.001
lambda_ = 0.001
h1 = 50

train = pd.read_csv('/content/data/mnist_train.csv.zip')
test = pd.read_csv('/content/data/mnist_test.csv.zip')

train = train.loc['1':'5000', :]
test = test.loc['1':'2000', :]

train = train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

x_train = train.loc[:, '1x1':'28x28']
y_train = train.loc[:, 'label']

x_test = test.loc[:, '1x1':'28x28']
y_test = test.loc[:, 'label']

x_train = x_train.values
y_train = y_train.values

x_test = x_test.values
y_test = y_test.values

nb_classes = 10
targets = y_train.reshape(-1)
y_train_onehot = np.eye(nb_classes)[targets]

nb_classes = 10
targets = y_test.reshape(-1)
y_test_onehot = np.eye(nb_classes)[targets]

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(784, input_shape=(784,), kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
model.add(layers.Dense(h1, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(lambda_), kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(lambda_), kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))

model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
             loss = 'mse',
             metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train_onehot, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test_onehot, batch_size=batch_size)

prediction = model.predict_classes(x_test)
print(prediction)

print(y_test[1:])
```

I've heard that a lot of the time when people have this problem, it's just a problem with data input. But I can't see any problem with that here since it almost always predicts wrongly (about as much as you would expect if it was random). How do I fix this problem?

Edit: Here are the specific results:

Last training step:

```python
Epoch 15/15
49999/49999 [==============================] - 3s 70us/sample - loss: 0.0309 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9615
```

Evaluation output:

```python
2000/2000 [==============================] - 0s 54us/sample - loss: 0.0352 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9310
[0.03524150168523192, 0.931]
```

Output from model.predict_classes:

```python
[9 9 0 ... 5 0 5]
```

Output from print(y_test):

```python
[9 0 0 7 6 8 5 1 3 2 4 1 4 5 8 4 9 2 4]
```

Comment: Why `print(y_test[1:])` in the code instead of `print(y_test)`? Can it be that your true labels are just starting from the second one so you are comparing with the wrong predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is, your loss function is wrong: you are in a multi-class classification setting, and you are using a loss function suitable for regression and not classification (MSE).

Change our model compilation to:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='SGD',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

See the Keras [MNIST MLP example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) for corroboration, and own answer in [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577) for more details (although here you actually have the inverse problem, i.e. regression loss in a classification setting).

Moreover, it is not clear if the MNIST variant you are using is already normalized; if not, you should normalize them yourself:

```
x_train = x_train.values/255
x_test = x_test.values/255
```

It is also not clear why you ask for a 784-unit layer, since this is actually the *second* layer of your NN (the first is implicitly set by the `input_shape` argument - see [Keras Sequential model input layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572674/keras-sequential-model-input-layer)), and it certainly does not need to contain one unit for each one of your 784 input features.

**UPDATE** (after comments):

> But why is MSE meaningless for classification?

This is a theoretical issue, not exactly appropriate for SO; roughly speaking, it is for the same reason we don't use linear regression for classification - we use *logistic* regression, the actual difference between the two approaches being exactly the loss function.  Andrew Ng, in his popular Machine Learning course at Coursera, explains this nicely - see his [Lecture 6.1 - Logistic Regression | Classification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-la3q9d7AKQ&t=0s&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN&index=33) at Youtube (explanation starts at ~ 3:00), as well as section **4.2 Why Not Linear Regression [for classification]?** of the (highly recommended and freely available) textbook [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) by Hastie, Tibshirani and coworkers.

> And MSE does give a high accuracy, so why doesn't that matter?

Nowadays, almost *anything* you throw at MNIST will "work", which of course neither makes it correct nor a good approach for more demanding datasets...

**UPDATE 2**:

> whenever I run with crossentropy, the accuracy just flutters around at ~10%

Sorry, cannot reproduce the behavior... Taking the [Keras MNIST MLP example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) with a simplified version of your model, i.e.:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(784, activation='linear', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=SGD(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

we easily end up with a ~ 92% **validation** accuracy after only 5 epochs:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=5,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.8974 - acc: 0.7801 - val_loss: 0.4650 - val_acc: 0.8823
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.4236 - acc: 0.8868 - val_loss: 0.3582 - val_acc: 0.9034
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.3572 - acc: 0.9009 - val_loss: 0.3228 - val_acc: 0.9099
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.3263 - acc: 0.9082 - val_loss: 0.3024 - val_acc: 0.9156
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.3061 - acc: 0.9132 - val_loss: 0.2845 - val_acc: 0.9196
```

Notice the `activation='linear'` of the first Dense layer, which is the equivalent of [not specifying anything](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense), like in your case (as I said, practically everything you throw to MNIST will "work")...

**Final advice**: Try modifying your model as:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(784, activation = 'relu',input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(h1, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

in order to use the better (and [default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense)) `'glorot_uniform'` initializer, and remove the `kernel_regularizer` args (they may be the cause of any issue - **always** start simple!)...

Comment: The reason I have MSE as my loss function is that when I used crossentropy, a lot of strange things occurred. I have another post with that information, but I didn't get any working answers. Here is the link to the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328966/tf-keras-loss-becomes-nan

Comment: @RonanVenkat MSE is meaningless for such classification problems, and that's really non-negotiable

Comment: @RonanVenkat please try to reproduce a Keras MNIST example first using the built-in MNIST data! God knows if the obscure MNIST variant you use are already normalized or not (you don't normalize them)...!

Comment: I checked and the data isn't automatically normalized, just so you know.

Comment: I know I can't compare losses, but I can compare accuracy, which is what I was doing. The problem is that the manual predictions are off, but the evaluation has high accuracy. MSE has a very good evaluation with the test set, but crossentropy has a very bad evaluation, no better than a random guess.

Comment: @RonanVenkat MSE here is **meaningless** - period. As for the individual predictions, you still don't show details after the corrective actions suggested - even before, did you actually show results of `print(y_test[1:])` instead of `print(y_test)`??? Hope you just have not just shifted the true labels by one position, and then worry why they do not agree with the predictions...

Comment: I think that was probably the problem. I was printing only the first few digits of y_test, so I was usually doing something like y_test[1:20]. I should have realized the indexing problem earlier, sorry. But why is MSE meaningless for classification? I know the formula and the derivative and I don't see why it wouldn't work. And MSE does give a high accuracy, so why doesn't that matter?

Comment: @RonanVenkat that's why we ask for a [MCVE], and not verbal assurances like "*it doesn't look right*"; for the questions, see update...

Comment: but the difference between linear and logistic regression is not only the cost, but also the hypothesis. I’ve seen a lot of Andrew Ng’s course, so I know some theory. And if crossentropy should work, why doesn’t it work at all here?

Comment: whenever I run with crossentropy, the accuracy just flutters around at ~10%.

Comment: @RonanVenkat sorry, cannot reproduce the behavior (it may be due to the regularizers); see last update & advice (my final word on the subject)...