# Why tf.keras loss becomes NaN when number of train images increases from 100 to 9000?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I am following a CNN example in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn).
Here are my code to prepare the CNN model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(7)) # 7 outputs for 7 classes which are 1, 2, 3, ..., 7
```

And this is how I train the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainGenerator, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=validationGenerator)
```

When `trainGenerator` has 80 images & `validationGenerator` has 20 images, everything is ok for the `val_loss` & `loss` like below from one of the epoch

```
Epoch 1/10
3/3 [==============================] - 1s 736ms/step - loss: 1.8475 - accuracy: 0.2500 - val_loss: 2.4287 - val_accuracy: 0.5500
```

When the `trainGenerator` got 9817 images & `validationGenerator` got 2454 images, the `val_loss` & `loss` become NaN

```
Epoch 1/10
307/307 [==============================] - 20s 63ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0090 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

The batch size in `trainGenerator` & `validationGenertor` is 32 (default value) in both scenarios above.

I have rescaled the images when I import the images to `trainGenerator` & `validationGenertor` using the

```
trainDataGen=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.2    
)
```

After that I create `trainGenerator` using `flow_from_dataframe` like below:

```
  trainGenerator = trainDataGen.flow_from_dataframe(
      dataframe=train_df,
      directory=trainingFilepath,
      x_col="filename",
      y_col="label",
      target_size=(100,100),
      class_mode="raw",
      subset="training"
  )
```

`validationGenerator` is created using the code above by replacing subset with `validation`

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328966/tf-keras-loss-becomes-nan) has been asked but it does not apply to my case as the problem persists when number of train images increases & I use `sparce_categorical_crossentropy`

1. Why do I get `NaN` in `val_loss` & `val_accuracy` is 0?
2. How do I fix it so it can work with more images in the train set?

Comment: please show the code for the generators. Are you sing flow from directory or flow from dataframe?

Comment: @GerryP, I have added codes above for the generators. I am using `flow_from_dataframe`. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I would do is to use categorical cross entropy. In your generators change class_mode to 'categorical'. In model.compile make loss='categorical_crossentropy. Not sure this will fix it but it can't hurt. Could be when you use more images, perhaps there are some Na
labels. Check your datafame for Na's.

Comment: I have tried categorical crossentropy. I got some value from `val_loss` & `val_accuracy`, but both values remain the same for all epochs although I use 200 epochs. Any advice?

Comment: I suspect the problem may be with the dataset.  What dataset are you using?

Comment: I am using a private image dateset which unfortunately could not be shared here due to NDA. I have accepted your answer as I got some value in `val_loss` & `val_accuracy`. I will tweak around with the model layers & raise a separate question if I have any.